# Adding child node to Stanford Tree

Tags: java, tree, stanford-nlp

I am attempting to add a new node to a stanford parse [tree](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html) although what I have currently tried is not working:

So I use TregexMatcher and get back a tree like:

```
(VP 
    (VB run) 
    (PP 
        (To to) 
        (NP 
            (DT the) 
            (NN shop) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

I am trying to insert (VBD did) to be the first child of (VP) giving the tree:

```
(VP 
    (VBD did)
    (VB run) 
    (PP 
        (To to) 
        (NP 
            (DT the) 
            (NN shop) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
private Tree addNode(Tree tree, Label posTag, Label value, int index) {

    SimpleTree posNode = new SimpleTree(posTag);
    posNode.setValue(posTag.value());

    SimpleTree valueNode = new SimpleTree(value);
    valueNode.setValue(value.value());

    posNode.addChild(valueNode);

    tree.insertDtr(posNode, index);
    return tree;
}
```

I have been using the [online documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/overview-summary.html) although I am not sure exactly how to approach this issue.

Where am I going wrong? Is there an example online someone could link me to?

EDIT: The altered tree after the above code is:

```
(VP
    ( ) 
    (VB run)
    (PP 
        (TO to)
        (NP 
            (DT the) 
            (NN shop)
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is using `SimpleTree`.  A `SimpleTree` is just a tree structure with no node labels, and so isn't useful for much. I've added a note in the documentation saying that. With `LabeledScoredTreeNode` it works fine:

```
private static Tree addNodeFixed(Tree tree, Label posTag, Label value, int index) {
  Tree posNode = new LabeledScoredTreeNode(posTag);
  posNode.setValue(posTag.value());
  Tree valueNode = new LabeledScoredTreeNode(value);
  valueNode.setValue(value.value());
  posNode.addChild(valueNode);

  tree.insertDtr(posNode, index);
  return tree;
}
```

However, if you're using Tregex to match trees anyway, you might find it easier to do things with Tsurgeon.  Watch for the infinite loops on insertions, though!

```
private static Tree addNodeTsurgeon(Tree tree, String tag, String word) {
  TregexPattern pat = TregexPattern.compile("__=root !> __ !< " + tag);
  TsurgeonPattern surgery = Tsurgeon.parseOperation(
          "insert (" + tag + " " + word +") >1 root");
  return Tsurgeon.processPattern(pat, surgery, tree);
}
```